# why I got a disorder result when I use Mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I thought that it must be some wrong in my code, but I can't find it.

In my program I have:

```
public static class BrowserMapper extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
```

and

```
public static class BrowserReduce extends
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, IntWritable, Text> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(result, key);
    }
}
```

my job configure like this:

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Job job = Job.getInstance();

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setMapperClass(BrowserMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(BrowserReduce.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setJarByClass(LogAnalysis.class);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);

    return 0;
}
```

when I run this job, I got a result like this:

```
175394  IE
1475014 chrome
508390  firefox
23566   opera
421729  other
1266627 safari
```

but the expected result like this:

```
1475014 chrome
1266627 safari
508390  firefox
421729  other
175394  IE
23566   opera
```

Any Idea ? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results is sorted by the key sent to the Reducer(e.g., IE, chrome...). Do you notice the second column are sorted in alphabetical order?

If you want to sort them by the sum count, you need to add another MapReduce step and set the count as the key.

Answer (score 1):

Create a private instance variable

```
TreeMap sortedMap = new TreeMap();
```

Instead of doing context.write(result, key); in your Reducer, store those value in TreeMap. `sortedMap.put(sum,key);`

In the cleanup method you can do a context.write() the way you want the output. The TreeMap sorts the output. So you will achieve what you are looking for.